# how can I handle NaN values when reading a parquet file in C++?

Tags: c++, parquet, apache-arrow

I have a parquet file to be read in C++.

I am currently reading with this script:

```
std::string parquet_path{"my.parquet"};
PARQUET_ASSIGN_OR_THROW(auto infile, arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open(parquet_path.c_str()));

auto schema = parquet::ReadMetaData(infile);
//std::cout<<schema->SerializeToString()<<std::endl;
parquet::StreamReader os{parquet::ParquetFileReader::Open(infile)};

int field1;
int64_t field2;

while (!os.eof())
{
    os>>field1>>field2>>parquet::EndRow;
    std::cout<<field1<<", "<<field2<<std::endl;
}
```

The problem is that I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'parquet::ParquetException'
  what():  Failed to read value for column 'field2' on row 0
```

Looking at the data in Python with Pandas with:

```
df = pd.read_parquet('my.parquet')
df.info()
```

I see that `field2` has 0 non-null values and it is of type `float64` but when using double in C++ (as suggested in the comments) I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'parquet::ParquetException'
  what():  Column physical type mismatch.  Column 'field2' has physical type 'INT64' not 'DOUBLE'
```

For this reason I am assuming that the problem is with the Nan values which in C++ are for float and bouble types but it is in contrast with the parquet schema, for which the field is int64.

So I was thinking if there's a way to manage such values when reading it? Or how can I drop the entire column?

Comment: I see only `int` and I do not see `float` or `double`! So how you can you have a `NaN`? From where it came form?

Comment: you are right, it represented as float. I checked it using python.

Comment: [`std::isnan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles more details? But it does not solve the case where only some values are NaN, does it?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you're asking so I can't help much more. What exactly is the problem you're having? Is the file failing to parse? Is it parsing but you can't tell that the values are NaN? something else?

Answer (score 0):

I guess IsNan may help:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan

With this function, you can check for NaN

Or you can read the fields into a string an then convert them to floats or doubles.